# Explicit 2-cocycle on a Hopf algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

I'm studying the theory of cocycles on Hopf algebras, but I would like to see an explicity 2-coclycle, for example, in the Lauret algebra $A=\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}]$. Is there someone who can write one? or who can tell me about some references with explicit examples?.